# Evaluation of files in GNU make conditional

Tags: gnu-make

```
all: start doSomeMagicToChangeRegFile end

start: $(OBJDIR)
    @$(TOUCH) build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG).reg || exit
    @$(MD5SUM) build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG).reg > build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN
    ...........

end: $(APPL_OBJ)
    ...........
    @$(MD5SUM) build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG).reg > build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END
    @$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN
    @$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END
ifneq ($(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN,$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END)
    @$(ECHO) "REBUILD"
    @$(RM) -fr build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG)/*.o*
    @$(MAKE) -i $(CONFIG)
else
    @$(ECHO) "DONE"
endif
```

This gnu make file builds some code with the Keil compiler and creates a reg file within this context. The code should be recompiled until the reg file doesn't change any more. There is a md5 hash calculation at the start and at the end. Both hashs are compared at the end. But this check results in an infinite loop. The evaluation of the ifneq conditional doesn't seem to work. The result of `@$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN` and `@$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END` are correct, but apparently not in the conditional. Why?

Comment: Silencing all your commands with `@` is an antipattern and complicates debugging tremendously.  Take those out and get used to `make -s` if you cannot cope with the regular output.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused about a few things.  First `ifeq`/`ifneq` are *string comparison* functions: they compare the strings `$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN` and `$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END`, which by definition will never be equal so the `ifneq` is always true.  `ifeq`/`ifneq` do not compare the contents of files.

Second, the make processor statements like `include`, `ifeq`, etc. are all parsed as the makefile is read in, long before make starts to actually run any rules.  So at the time the `ifneq` is parsed none of the recipe has been invoked.

If you want a conditional that runs as part of the recipe, then you have to actually make it part of the recipe and use shell conditionals, not make conditionals.

*ETA* Something like this:

```
RMAKE = $(MAKE)

end: $(APPL_OBJ)
        ...........
        @$(MD5SUM) build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG).reg > build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END
        @$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN
        @$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END
        @if [ `$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN` != `$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END` ]; then \
            $(ECHO) "REBUILD"; \
            $(RM) -fr build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG)/*.o*; \
            $(RMAKE) -i $(CONFIG); \
        else \
            $(ECHO) "DONE"; \
        fi
```

The `RMAKE` trick is needed if you ever want to run `make -n` and have it do the right thing.

@triplee is right, though, using `@` before all these lines is a bad idea.  It makes debugging your makefiles super-annoying.  At the very least you should not add them until after your makefile is fully developed and working.

Comment: Like that?
`ifneq ($(shell HEAD build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN),$(shell HEAD build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END))`

Comment: No.  That will run the command `$(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN` in the shell and return the output and compare it, yes.  However that will still run the command as the makefile is read in, before the recipe is run (so before the earlier command lines are run).  I'll edit my response with an example.

Comment: The if condition seems to be completely ignored. I'm using GNU make for windows, could that be the reason?

Comment: Depends on what Windows environment you're using.  Are you using a UNIX shell with make?  Or Windows command.com?  If the latter I can't help you: I don't do Windows.  But you'll need to write the equivalent if-statement in Windows batch syntax, whatever it is.  You _cannot_ use GNU make features like `ifneq` to check information that is generated by the recipe.

Comment: `$(if $(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN != $(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END, \
  @$(ECHO) "REBUILD" \
 , \
  @$(ECHO) "DONE" \
 )`

Comment: Seems to work. But how can i execute the other two commands after "REBUILD"?

Comment: @JDoe that cannot work.  The GNU make `if` function evaluates its first argument and if it's false (which is defined by GNU make as "the empty string"), it runs the then-part.  Here the condition (first argument) will never be empty, so it will never be false.  GNU make's `if` function does NOT parse operators like `=`, `!=`, etc.  In addition, GNU make evaluates the entire recipe, all lines, up front before it begins running any part of the recipe.

Comment: I'll repeat my statement above: you cannot, at all, in any way, ever, use any GNU make facility (function, variable, etc.) to implement the test you're trying to write.  It _must_ be written as part of your recipe, using your shell's syntax, not make syntax.

Comment: `$(shell $(TEST) $(shell $(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_BEGIN) != $(shell $(HEAD) build/$(CONFIG)/MD5SUM_REG_END) && \
  $(ECHO) "REBUILD" \
  $(RM) -fr build/$(CONFIG)/$(CONFIG)/*.o* \
  $(RMAKE) -i $(CONFIG) \
 || \
  $(ECHO) "DONE")`

Comment: This isn't working properly, but at least it isn't ignored. How would be the correct syntax?

Comment: See my above comment.  The `$(shell ...)` function is a GNU make function, and as I said, you cannot use any GNU make facility (function, variable, etc.) to implement the test you're trying to write.  You must implement it completely using shell operations, you cannot use GNU make operations (other than simple variables that contain pathnames etc.).  I can't tell you the correct syntax, because it depends on the shell you're using.  Since you're on Windows, you may or may not be using a UNIX shell (depends on how your GNU make was built).  If not, I can't help.